Analytical Method used in harmonics oscillator v.s the Hydrogen Atom in quantum mechanics
I was studying quantum mechanics by Griffthis, he used Analytical Method in two times, first with harmonic oscillator in chapter(2), and second in chapter(4) for Hydogen Atom, in each case we got a differenctial equation after changing the variables and so on, i'll mention the two differential equations that were derived in each case:
For harmonic oscillator: $$\frac{d^2 \psi}{d\xi^2} = \left( \xi^2 - K \right) \psi$$
For the hydrogen atom: $$\frac{d^2 u}{d\rho^2} = \left[ 1 - \frac{\rho_0}{\rho} + \frac{\ell (\ell + 1)}{\rho^2} \right] u$$
Then in proceeding our solution methods, we examine the asymptotic form of the solutions.

For the harmonic oscillator case we have taken the limit as $\xi \rightarrow \infty$.

While in the hydrogen atom case, we have taken the limit as $\rho \rightarrow \infty$, and as $\rho \rightarrow 0$.


My question is what is the difference in each case that let us to consider a different limits of the asymptotic form?

For the harmonic oscillator the wave function $\psi(\xi)$
extends from $\xi=-\infty$ to $\xi=+\infty$.
(And there is nothing weird at $\xi=0$.)
Therefore you first consider the asymptotic behavior
of $\psi(\xi)$ at these two boundaries $\xi=\pm\infty$.
And it happens to be that the asymptotic behavior
at both ends is the same.
But the radial wave function $u(\rho)$ of the hydrogen atom
extends from $\rho=0$ to $\rho=\infty$, because a radius is always positive.
Therefore you first consider the asymptotic behavior of $u(\rho)$
at these two boundaries $\rho=0$ and $\rho=\infty$.

Thanks for your answer. I understand that we are interested in endpoints in each case, but my problem was how to prove it mathematically in the case of the harmonic oscillator as we approach zero. Nevertheless, I found the detailed solution in Shankar's textbook, and it was consistent with your explanation. Thanks again!

@Fadi The differential equation of the harmonic oscillator is well-behaved at $\xi=0$, while that of the hydrogen atom has a singularity at $\rho=0$.

I got it now. Thanks again for your clarification!
